# JenkinsAPI Python - Trying to get build information

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Here is what I am doing using the JenkinsAPI for Python

```
# Python scipt to get build information

# Import jenkins API and check Jenkins Version

import jenkinsapi
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
from jenkinsapi.build import Build

J = Jenkins('http://test.com')
job = J['MY_JOB_NAME']

print "Jenkins version:", J.version, "\n"

print jenkinsapi.api.get_latest_test_results('http://test.com','MY_JOB_NAME'), "\n"


B= Build('http://test.com',22,job)
print B.get_resultset()
```

I keep getting this error which I am unable to understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 19, in <module>
    print B
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkinsapi-0.2.18-py2.7.egg/jenkinsapi/build.py", line 49, in __str__
    return self._data['fullDisplayName']
KeyError: 'fullDisplayName'
svikani@myunix:~$ python myscript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 19, in <module>
    print B.get_resultset()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkinsapi-0.2.18-py2.7.egg/jenkinsapi/build.py", line 331, in get_resultset
    result_url = self.get_result_url()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkinsapi-0.2.18-py2.7.egg/jenkinsapi/build.py", line 325, in get_result_url
    return url_tpl % (self._data["url"], config.JENKINS_API)
KeyError: 'url'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there are uninitialized variables in the *Build* instance.

You're constructing a *Build* instance yourself, but you should probably go through the API of the *Jenkins* instance to get the job and the build you're interested in.

```
import jenkinsapi
j = jenkinsapi.jenkins.Jenkins('http://jenkins:8080/')
job = j.get_job(JOB_NAME)  # or j[JOB_NAME]
build = job.get_build(BUILD_ID)
print build.get_resultset()
```

Comment: I executed the script, but I don't see any build information except the build number and the Build Name. Do you know how I can actually get all the build information (code coverage, other information ?)

Comment: I can't help with code coverage specifically, but in my builds with unit tests, the Results object from `build.get_resultset()` has `keys()` and `items()` methods.